# ftp_put write outside home directory

Tags: php

I have the following folder structure on my remote site:

```
/home/John
/flowers
```

When I login using ftp_login, the active directory is set to /home/John. If I write:

`ftp_put($conn_id, "tulip.jpg", "tulip.jpg")`

the file ends up in the /home/John folder as expected.

However I want to upload it into the "flowers" directory. I tried two methods that didn't work:

1. `ftp_put($conn_id, "../../flowers/tulip.jpg", "tulip.jpg")` but the file is still uploaded in /home/John
2. I tried to use `ftp_chdir` as follows:

`ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/flowers')`

But it ends up in an error:

ftp_chdir(): /flowers: No such file or directory

If I have folders inside /home/John I can use ftp_chdir to change the active directory and point to them, but I cannot do anything outside the folder. Despite not being in the root directory, ftp_pwd($conn_id) returns '/' (I was expecting /home/John)

Logging in with Winscp I can access and write in the "flowers" folder, so there are no rights issues.

How can I do the same thing in PHP with ftp_put?

Comment: Try `./flowers` to refer from current dir. A dir beginning with `/` will look from the root directory.

Comment: Try `../flowers` for step back one level (the `..`) and then step up one level to the `/flowers` directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that user "John" could connect to that server in two ways: via FTP or via SFTP (using the SAME username and password in both cases). When connected via SFTP the root directory was '/' and so, the 'flowers' folder was accessible.

When connected via FTP, it was chrooted to /home/John and therefore it was impossible to move up.

Sadly for me, in winscp I was connecting using the SFTP connection, and therefore the adventure started :)

Comment: Don't use FTP at all it's not secure without key exchange.